# Shiny R- Why aren't formatStyle() changes visible in my output data table?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I am trying to change the format and style of my output table in Shiny using formatStyle() but the changes are not visible. What might be wrong? For example, I want the "Yes" to be bold but the final results do not show these changes.
This is my final output:

[image]

This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(readxl)
var_version_tables <- read_excel("test_2_filtros_2.xlsx")
df<-var_version_tables

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("var_1", "Categories", choices = unique(df$var_1)),
  selectInput("var_2", "Tables", choices = NULL, multiple = T),
  DT::dataTableOutput("data")
)





server <- function(input, output, session) {
  categories <- reactive({
    filter(df, var_1 == input$var_1)
  })
  observeEvent(categories(), {
    choices <- unique(categories()$var_2)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "var_2", choices = choices) 
  })
  
  
  output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$var_2)
    
    table<-categories() %>% 
      filter(var_2 %in% input$var_2) %>% 
      select(var_2, var_3)%>%
      mutate(result="Yes") %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = var_2, values_from = result, values_fill = "No")%>%
      rename(Columns=var_3)
    
    table_1<-DT::datatable(table, filter= 'top',options = list(order=list(0,'asc'), dom='t', pageLength= 100, autoWidth = TRUE),rownames = FALSE)
    table_2<-DT::formatStyle(table_1, columns = NULL, fontWeight = styleEqual(c('No', 'Yes'), c('normal', 'bold')))
    
    
    
    
    
    
    return(table_2)
    
    
    
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And this is my input data:

| var_1 | var_2 | var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | table1 | column1 |
| red | table1 | column4 |
| red | table1 | column3 |
| blue | table2 | column1 |
| blue | table2 | column2 |
| blue | table2 | column3 |
| blue | table2 | column4 |
| blue | table3 | column3 |
| blue | table3 | column10 |
| blue | table3 | column15 |
| blue | table3 | column4 |
| blue | table3 | column5 |
| pink | table4 | column1 |
| pink | table4 | column2 |
| pink | table4 | column11 |
| pink | table4 | column10 |
| pink | table4 | column5 |
| pink | table4 | column6 |
| pink | table4 | column7 |
| blue | table5 | column1 |
| blue | table5 | column2 |
| blue | table5 | column3 |
| yellow | table6 | column9 |
| yellow | table6 | column10 |
| pink | table7 | column6 |
| pink | table7 | column7 |
| pink | table7 | column8 |

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `NULL` for `columns` in `formatStyle` use the column names from `table`.

```
    table_2 <-
      DT::formatStyle(table_1,
                      columns = colnames(table),
                      fontWeight = styleEqual(c('No', 'Yes'), c('normal', 'bold')))
```

[image]